# Why am I receiving this error 'illegal start of type'?

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, syntax-error, startup

I am getting the error in the part where it says (final (String[] args)). It would be great if somebody knows why this error is occurring. Thanks in advance! I have included the code.

```
public class PartOne {


    private static Object BufferedReader;

    public static <String> void PartOne (final (String[] args))

    {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words-sowpods.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            String everything = sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: final String[] args => remove the parenthesis

Comment: What are you trying to do at `public static <String> void PartOne (final (String[] args)) {` because there are too many things which don't look right like fact that you declared *generic type* with name String, which means that each time you will use `String` there it will represent that generic type, not `java.lang.String` type. Also your method have same name as class name which is usually what we do in *constructor* but constructors shouldn't have *return* type (not even `void`) and wouldn't be `static`.

Comment: Also, post the error message you are getting. It adds more context.

Comment: First of all, include intention behind that code because for now it looks something like `class SomeClass { adlskfjaslkdfja(asdfjasdf)..}`. To correct part `adlskfjaslkdfja(asdfjasdf)` we would need to know what you *expect* it to do (what it is supposed to be).

Comment: If that is supposed to be `main` method (based on your comments under the answer) then change `public static <String> void PartOne (final (String[] args))` into `public static void main(String[] args)` (just like error message tells you to).

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things wrong here-
public static  void PartOne (final (String[] args))

1. why u have making generic type as String even though is void
2. param is incorrect

Please find the correct implementation :

```
 public static void PartOne(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words-sowpods.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            String everything = sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get the following error when I do it that way, Error: Main method not found in class PartOne, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: @CianRyan So what is stopping you from applying that advice from error message?

Comment: I now get a message saying: "Error: Main method not found in class PartOne, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)"